# simple bst file

Tags: bibtex

I am looking for a BibTex .bst file that references with numbers in the order references appear, and the references themselves include only:
-author with initials

-journal

-volume

-start page

-year

with minimal space between references

as this example:

"this database consolidates PPI data available in multiple primary interaction databases, namely BIND [1], BioGRID [2]..."

1. Alfarano C. et al. Nucleic Acids Res 33: D418 (2005).
2. Stark C. et al. Nucleic Acids Res 39: D698 (2011).

I have looked for one that fits those requirements [here](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html), but all of them include all the fields.

Does anyone know where I can find a .bst file like that one? Or which would be the best one in the link above to modify, and how to modify it? Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the program `makebst` / `makebst` ? It's a very good tool that should be able to help you. If you just run the program using `latex makebst`, it will leaad you through, it's nice, interactive.

Comment: It would be easier to do with `biblatex`.

Comment: Your set of requirements -- in particular, the requirement to show only FirstAuthor et al if there are three or more authors -- is probably sufficiently unique as to make it unlikely somebody else having the same set of requirement. But, as @tohecz has already comment, there's the entirely menu-driven `makebst` utility (part of the [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package) that makes it straightforward to create one's own bespoke `.bst` file.

Comment: I wasn't aware of makebst! many thanks, it did exactly what I wanted

Comment: `makebst` seems to have been the answer, i hence vote to close as duplicate.